# Aggregate tag names in Django Taggit

Tags: python, django, tagging, django-taggit

I am using the **django taggit** library. I have a Queryset that lists objects, which have a few tags attached to each object. How to get them all in one query?

While I know how to get tags for each objects on model level, I haven't found a way to do so at Queryset level. How to get all objects tags in Queryset in the same query?
Something like

```
Book.objects.filter(year=2020).values('bookname', 'published_at', 'tag_names_list')[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Queryset.values('main_group_field').annotate(all_tags=StringAgg('tags__name', ',')) solves it.